# HQL - SELECT NEW with null foreign key

Tags: hql

I've got this HQL;

```
@Query("SELECT NEW com.witbiz.witgym.dto.ExerciseDTO(s.id,s.note,s.exerciseType.id,s.trainingSession.id,s.reps,s.sets,s.weight,s.pauseEachSerie,"
        + "s.sortOfExecution,s.exerciseType.name,s.exerciseType.picture.url) FROM exercise s")
```

**My problem is:** 
When an Exercise (Domain Object) isn't related to a Picture (Domain Object), so I guess that s.exerciseType.picture is null, the query doesn't return the row. 
Therefore, some elements are missing from my list!

If I cancel "s.exerciseType.picture" from the contructor then the query returns all the rows correctly.

How can I get a complete list containing all my exercises using this contructor? I want null passed to my constructor if there isn't a related Picture.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem of yours, did you get it resolve by any chance? Thanks :)